# Check if element exists python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ui-automation

I'm trying to locate element by

```
element=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("text")
```

in Python selenium and the element does not always exist. Is there a quick line to check if it exists and get NULL or FALSE in place of the error message when it doesn't exist?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `quick statement to check`? Selenium doesn't supports `statement`. You have to write a line/block of code.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("text")` is quick enough way to check if element exists... Can you be more explicit about what you want your code to do?

Comment: It gives error message when the element does not exist. Is it possible get a NULL or FALSE when it does not exist?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can implement `try`/`except` block as below to check whether element present or not:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    element=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("text")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No element found")
```

or check the same with one of `find_elements_...()` methods. It should return you empty list or list of elements matched by passed selector, but no exception in case no elements found:

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("text")
if not elements:
    print("No element found")  
else:
    element = elements[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the element does not appear at once, for this case we need to use explicit wait:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)

def is_element_exist(text):
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, text)))
    except TimeoutException:
        return False
```

**Solution without `try/ except`:**

```
def is_element_exist(text):
    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, text)))
    return None if elements else False
```

How explicit wait works you can read [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```