# Check If element exists in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, if-statement, xpath, ui-automation

Following is my python selenium code

```
def provideDetails(self, titleEleName, titleText, sbmtBtnName, dropdownOptn, dropdownName):

        self.ui.jobs.setJobTitleEleName(titleEleName, titleText)

        elem = self.ui.jobs.selectButton(dropdownName)

        if elem.is_displayed():
            self.ui.jobs.selectButton(dropdownName)
            self.ui.sleep(4)
            self.ui.jobs.selectAor(dropdownOptn)
        else:
            self.ui.jobs.selectAddAors(dropdownOptn)
            self.ui.sleep(4)

        self.ui.jobs.selectButton(sbmtBtnName)
```

I have to check, if the 'elem' is present or not.
And if it is present, 'if' condition should happen, and if not, 'else' condition should work. 
I tried this code. And I got this error "Attribute error: None Type object has no attribute 'is_displayed'.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Also, Is there any alternative method to check if an element exists and follow with the if else commands

Comment: Can you try checking what `elem` holds before getting into the loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if element exists python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695874/check-if-element-exists-python-selenium)

Comment: @eduPeeth elem clicks the button.

Comment: provide code in selectButton method

Comment: @muraliselenium def _selectSpan(self, span):
        """Clicks a span by text - submit, cancel, etc."""
        self.ui.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//span[contains(text(),\'{}\')]".format(span)).click()

    def selectButton(self, button):
        """Clicks a button in the Provide details page for Job, Crew, etc."""
        self._selectSpan(button)

Comment: or is there any alternative way to check whether an element exists ? and follow with the if else commands

Answer (score 2):

A good way is to use an [explicit wait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html). An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. Look at the example:

```
self.ui.jobs.setJobTitleEleName(titleEleName, titleText)
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)

try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, dropdownName)))
    self.ui.jobs.selectButton(dropdownName)
    self.ui.sleep(4)
    self.ui.jobs.selectAor(dropdownOptn)
except TimeoutException:
    self.ui.jobs.selectAddAors(dropdownOptn)
    self.ui.sleep(4)

self.ui.jobs.selectButton(sbmtBtnName)
```

**The solution with if / else statement:**

```
def provideDetails(self, titleEleName, titleText, sbmtBtnName, dropdownOptn, dropdownName):
    self.ui.jobs.setJobTitleEleName(titleEleName, titleText)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
    elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.NAME, dropdownName))) # will return a list of elements

    if elem:
        self.ui.jobs.selectButton(dropdownName)
        self.ui.sleep(4)
        self.ui.jobs.selectAor(dropdownOptn)
    else:
        self.ui.jobs.selectAddAors(dropdownOptn)
        self.ui.sleep(4)

    self.ui.jobs.selectButton(sbmtBtnName)
```

*An expectation for checking that there is at least one element visible on a web page. locator is used to find the element returns the list of WebElements once they are located.*

Imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Comment: If element is found it doesn't mean that it is displayed. Do not mislead OP. You can update your code as `if elem and elem[0].is_displayed():`

Comment: @Andersson I'm sorry. I have rewrote my answer according to best practices. Please, check, I'm interested in your opinion.

Comment: OK. But now it seem that the solution doesn't meet OP requirement to use `if`/`else` construction

Comment: I see. Let's leave two solutions for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment `selectButton` will perform click action but not returning web element. Let me explain in java

```java
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//elementPath"));
```

Here is `e` is web element on which i can click

```java
 e.click();
```

Or can verify if element is displayed or not (in if condition)

```java
e.isDisplayed();
```

but `WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//elementPath")).click();` is not valid one. In Java it show you exception in editor like eclipse as soon as you write it. so `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//elementPath")).click();` will not return to element to check is displayed or not.