# Program ended without completing the task

Tags: python-3.x, loops, selenium, while-loop

When I run my script, it is ended before completing the task that is in `while` loop.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://example.com')
#input("Press any key to continue1")
s_b_c_status = "False"
while s_b_c_status == "True":
    try:
        if(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='button' and @title='Status']")):
            s_b_c_status = "True"
    except NoSuchElementException:
        s_b_c_status = "False"
if(s_b_c_status == "True"):
    print("Scanning Done!")
else:
print("Error")
```

As my site is not having the element it should always print `Error`, but when I run my code it prints `Error` only once (though it is checked in `while` loop).

**What I exactly need:**
The script should check whether the element is there or not till the element is there, and then run the rest code.

Comment: How much time you usually need to wait until element appear?

Comment: Between 10-20 seconds, **I don't want to use `time.sleep()`** here...

Comment: @Rabe I think there is a little mixup in the _usecase_ as you mentioned `my site is not having the element it should always print Error` but later you mentioned `check whether the element is there or not till the element is there`, so the main question is would the element be there? If so what is your next coarse of action with the element? Solution will depend on that condition.

Comment: The element will be there for 100% sure, but it is not fixed after how much of time it will appear, as it will be according to the users internet speed...

Comment: @Rabe Okay and what is your next coarse of action with the element? _retrieving some attribute_ (e.g. _text_) or invoke _click()_?

Comment: Just to check whether it is there or not, and if it is there it should run my rest of code, which is not related to that element!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has an obvious flaw in logic:

```
s_b_c_status = "False"
while s_b_c_status == "True"
```

You've defined `s_b_c_status` as `"False"`, so your `while` loop will not do even a single iteration...

If you need to wait for element to appear in DOM, try to implement [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://example.com')

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='button' and @title='Status']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Element not found")
```

Comment: What does 20 means? it will check till 20 seconds or after 20 seconds?Also how can we give a message if it doesn't find in 20 seconds?

Comment: @Rabe , it means *wait up to 20 seconds for element to appear in DOM*. In case element didn't appear, `TimeoutException` will be raised. Check updated answer

Comment: If element is found in 2 secs, then also it will wait for 20 or it will continue after 2 secs?

Comment: @Rabe Continue after 2 seconds

Comment: I'll be thankful if I get the solution with `while` loop too, for my future reference...

Comment: @Rabe Solution with `while` loop will be more complex and it should contain some condition to break the loop somehow. Otherwise it will run infinitely... Also `time.sleep` should be used to wait, for instance, 1 second until next check for presence of element...   Do you still need `while` loop solution?

Comment: You don't need a `while` solution... this takes care of your check without using a `while`. This is the better way to do this.